# How to get the user's response which falls into default fallback intent in dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am using open-ended response in Dialogflow, i.e, the app asks a question and user enters the response and then the system asks another question.

Consider the scenario, user enters: the starters were amazing. There is no such training phrase to match this response, so it goes into default fallback intent. I am handling this request in a webhook so I need this user's response so that it can be stored into the database.

How am I able to get this response?

Update:
After using queryResult.queryText I am getting this error:
Error: No response has been set. Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise to the intent handler? at DialogflowConversation.response (/srv/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/actionssdk/conversation/conversation.js:237:19) at DialogflowConversation.serialize (/srv/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/conv.js:160:129) at Function. (/srv/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:173:28) at Generator.next () at fulfilled (/srv/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:19:58) at  at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

The code for the Default Fallback Intent is this:

```
app.intent('Default Fallback Intent', (conv) => {
    senddata[check_fallback] = queryResult.queryText;        
    conv.add(queryResult.queryText); //just for confirmation 
    conv.ask(qstion[2]);
});
```

Update 2:

Flow of the code: If the user responses with any of the open ended response it goes to the Default Fallback Intent. The code is following:

//This is the code where the user enters the open ended response

```
app.intent('Answer3', (conv) => {
    const logout = conv.parameters.logout_survey;
    const help = conv.parameters.help_survey;
    if(help === 'can you help me' || help === 'help' || help === 'help me'){
        checkhelp_logout = "help";
        flag_log_help = 4;
        conv.ask('Would you like some help?');
    }
    else if(logout === 'logout'){
        checkhelp_logout = "logout";
        flag_log_help = 4;
        conv.ask('Did you say logout?');
    }
});
```

//This is the code where the open-ended response is handled

```
app.intent('Default Fallback Intent', (conv) => {
    senddata[2] = conv.body.originalDetectInetntRequest.payload.queryResult.queryText;
    //The following code is just for confirmation that what user enters the same response is stored
    conv.add(conv.body.originalDetectInetntRequest.payload.queryResult.queryText;)
    conv.ask(qstion[3]);
});
```

Following is the error:

Error: No response has been set. Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise to the intent handler? at DialogflowConversation.response (/srv/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/actionssdk/conversation/conversation.js:237:19) at DialogflowConversation.serialize (/srv/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/conv.js:160:129) at Function. (/srv/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:173:28) at Generator.next () at fulfilled (/srv/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:19:58) at  at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It will help us a great deal if you include in your question the code you are trying to use, any errors that you're getting, and any other information that may help us help you. The more info you provide, the better. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

In the Intent Handler for the "Default Fallback Intent" you will want to look at the `queryResult.queryText` parameter of the JSON in the [request body](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-webhook#webhook_request).

If you are using the [actions-on-google-nodejs library](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs), this is in `conv.body.originalDetectInetntRequest.payload.queryResult.queryText`.

Comment: On using the queryResult.queryText, I am getting this error: ReferenceError: queryResult is not defined at app.intent

Comment: Can you update your question to show the code you are trying to use?

Comment: I think I found the right path and updated the answer.

Comment: Please update your question with the exact source you're using now and the exact error you're getting.

Comment: Updated the question.